# Clerk authMiddleware() is not being used even though it is in my middleware.ts file which is in the root of the application

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, error-handling, tailwind-css

```
    import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
    
    
    export default authMiddleware({});
    
    export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],

};
```

I get the Error: Clerk: auth() was called but it looks like you aren't using authMiddleware in your middleware file. Please use authMiddleware and make sure your middleware matcher is configured correctly and it matches this route or page. I had the middleware file use paths to get it to my api route which is api/stores/route.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too. Seems to have started happening after I restarted my machine. The only solution I've found is moving the `middleware.ts` into the `app` directory but this doesn't fix it for me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with the following steps:

1. Keeping the `middleware.ts` in the root (I'm not using a `src` folder)
2. I updated to Node `v20.7.0` from `18.0.0`

Comment: Yes this was exactly the problem, that has helped a lot. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I moved `middleware.ts` to src, and it worked!

[image: directory structure]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by removing the following from the middleware file.

```
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using turbo flag in `next dev --turbo` it wont work! Remove that falg in `package.json` (scripts section) and try again! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I moved `middleware.ts` the file outside the `App` directory

Answer (score 0):

Removing the /pages folder worked for me.
Middleware wasn't working before this.

`Next.js 14.1.3`

`node v20.11.1`

structure => `src/app/middleware.ts`

Answer (score 0):

The think which i used to resolve this problem is "move the middleware file to main folder (my-app folder) "

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).