Getting error in nextjs app with clerk plugin

NEXTJS VERSION : 14.2.5
 "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/backend": "1.6.2",
    "@clerk/clerk-react": "5.4.0",
    "@clerk/shared": "2.5.0",
    "@clerk/types": "4.13.0",
    "crypto-js": "4.2.0",
    "path-to-regexp": "6.2.2",
    "server-only": "0.0.1",
    "tslib": "2.4.1"
  },

MIDDLEWARE JS CODE :
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default clerkMiddleware();
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

TRIED CODE :
   import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default authMiddleware(); export const config = {   matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"], };


import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default clerkMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: [
    "/",
    "/api/webhook",
    "/question/:id",
    "/tags",
    "/tags/:id",
    "/profile/:id",
    "/community",
    "/jobs",
  ],
  ignoredRoutes: ["/api/webhook", "/api/chatgpt"],
});
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};


I guess your middleware.js is in the wrong place. Is it being called without clеrk, etc.?

@Armen was outside in app added it into src/middleware.js both not working

Did you follow all the steps in the docs https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs exactly? I haven’t used Clerk myself, but if needed, I can take a look. However, check again before that. But the main thing is to first make sure that middleware.(js/ts) is being called.

@Armen yes have made all the things as required in clerk package still facing the same issue

I will take a look tomorrow.

As I understand it, there might be more than one solution to your problem. Take a look at this https://github.com/clerk/clerk-next-app-router-starter/issues/2 it’s all about that issue. I also created a project with Next.js and Clerk a few minutes ago and didn’t encounter this error. And also take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77108110/clerk-authmiddleware-is-not-being-used-even-though-it-is-in-my-middleware-ts-f
